# Xcode Build error with React Native "___cxa_increment_exception_refcount"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, flipper

I'm getting the following error when trying to build to a device in Xcode. It works fine on the simulator.

Xcode 12.5 and React Native 0.63.3
I've tried a clean build. deleted and reinstalled Pods

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "___cxa_increment_exception_refcount", referenced from:
> folly::cxxabi_cxa_exception_sans_reserve() in libFlipper-Folly.a(Exception.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
> architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
> 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Additional Output

> Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appName.app/appName normal (in target 'appName' from project 'appName')
> cd /Users/username/Desktop/appName/appName/appName/ios
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphoneos -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Analytics -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CocoaAsyncSocket -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DoubleConversion -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-Boost-iOSX -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-DoubleConversion -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-Fmt -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-Folly -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-Glog -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-PeerTalk -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flipper-RSocket -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FlipperKit -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Folly -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PromisesObjC -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNAnalytics -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNCAsyncStorage -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNCMaskedView -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNFBAnalytics -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNFBApp -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNFBAuth -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNFBFirestore -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNFBMessaging -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNGestureHandler -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNReanimated -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNScreens -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNVectorIcons -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-Core -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-CoreModules -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTAnimation -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTBlob -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTImage -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTLinking -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTNetwork -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTSettings -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTText -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTVibration -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-cxxreact -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsi -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsiexecutor -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsinspector -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ReactCommon -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Yoga -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/YogaKit -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/abseil -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-C++ -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-Core -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/glog -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/leveldb-library -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libevent -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/react-native-fbsdk -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/react-native-safe-area-context -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/react-native-video -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/username/Desktop/appName/appName/appName/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/username/Desktop/appName/appName/appName/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/username/Desktop/appName/appName/appName/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/OpenSSL -filelist /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appName.build/Debug-iphoneos/appName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appName.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appName.build/Debug-iphoneos/appName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appName_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appName.build/Debug-iphoneos/appName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appName.swiftmodule -ObjC -lAnalytics -lBoringSSL-GRPC -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFBSDKCoreKit -lFBSDKLoginKit -lFBSDKShareKit -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseFirestore -lFirebaseInstallations -lFirebaseMessaging -lFlipper -lFlipper-Boost-iOSX -lFlipper-DoubleConversion -lFlipper-Fmt -lFlipper-Folly -lFlipper-Glog -lFlipper-PeerTalk -lFlipper-RSocket -lFlipperKit -lFolly -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleUtilities -lPromisesObjC -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNAnalytics -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCMaskedView -lRNFBAnalytics -lRNFBApp -lRNFBAuth -lRNFBFirestore -lRNFBMessaging -lRNGestureHandler -lRNReanimated -lRNScreens -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lYoga -lYogaKit -labseil -lc++ -lgRPC-C++ -lgRPC-Core -lglog -lleveldb-library -llibevent -lnanopb -lreact-native-fbsdk -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lreact-native-video -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreTelephony -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenSSL -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accelerate -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework UserNotifications -ObjC -lc++ -lPods-appName -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appName.build/Debug-iphoneos/appName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-bjouqajvpdjdyzhjhrftjpxofoty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appName.app/appName

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same happening to me. Using RN 0.63.4

Just found a solution that worked in my case:

I had this in my Podfile before I deleted and reinstalled Pods:

```
use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.92.0'})
```

Turns out the newest version of Flipper-Folly (2.6.9) is causing this issue.
Replace that line with:

```
use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.92.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.7'})
```

should fix your issue as well.

Comment: This work but if I use Hermes, then it does not work: i have `ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h:1051:5: 'atomic_notify_one<unsigned long>' is unavailable`

Comment: I am more or less having this exact issue, but my `use_flipper` line is commented out and never used

Comment: Seems like the issue for me was that I had changed the build device in xCode to some random simulator, an x86 one? Since I'm on M1, it won't work. The RN CLI Simulator, and `Product > Archive` must build for correct architecture -so I had never seen the issue before.

Comment: Had this issue while upgrading RN to 0.67.
I fixed the build issue with your answer and this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69565059/7895901

Comment: I have disabled Flipper and yet see the error. Any idea how to fix that?