# XCode 12 error building project with error libDoubleConversion.a, building for arm64 but attempting to link with file built for x86_64

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am getting following error when trying to run a react-native project in xcode simulator

```
ignoring file ../libDoubleConversion.a, building for iOS Simulator-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToPrecision(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const"
```

Here is how my xcode is configured

[image: xcode architectures tab]

Also added VALID_ARCHS in pod file and in project

[image: xcode user-defined tab]

Tried to add Linked Binary with libraries libDoubleConversion.a it didnt help. I also tried to exlude arm64 in Excluded architectures but then the error reverses Simulator-x86_64 -> Simulator-arm64 but on different file, Tried to use Xcode 13 beta same thing. So i got the point i am just going in circles and cant find a solution to successfuly run this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273669/1393695

> Turns out the newest version of Flipper-Folly (2.6.9) is causing this
> issue. Replace that line
>
> ```
> use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.92.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.7'})
> ```

With this i got an error in Xcode `could not find swiftSwiftOneOnoneSupport...`, then i added this lib in `Link binary with files`. And managed to run the build successfully.