# duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr&&)' React Native 0.66 with hermes enabled

Tags: xcode, react-native, flipper, react-native-hermes

After updating my app to react-native v0.66.0, I keep getting this error if hermes is enabled. I tried to delete DerivedData folder, podfile podfile.lock... but nothing helped

terminal output

```
duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr&&)' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr const&)' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::onNoExceptionError(char const*)' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::exceptionStr(folly::exception_wrapper const&)' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::uninit_' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::ExceptionPtr::ops_' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::SharedPtr::ops_' in:
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
    /Users/cuongtd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ekbbcdnefrapxuertuowclstsjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

ios/podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'MyApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0', :source => 'https://github.com/ElfSundae/CocoaPods-Specs.git'

  use_flipper!()
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target| 
      aggregate_target.user_project.native_targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift', '$(inherited)']
        end
      end
      aggregate_target.user_project.save
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
       end
    end
    `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' #{installer.sandbox.root}/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
  end
end
```

I want to use flipper to debug my app and hermes is enabled, thank all.

Edit: I can build the project from Xcode

Comment: Can you try changing your podfile to use `use_flipper!({ "Flipper-DoubleConversion" => "1.1.7" })`? I had a similar issue today and fixed it through that. See https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/235#issuecomment-863308604

Comment: thank @JeroenVannevel. I tried it, it worked only when hermes was disabled

Comment: Yeah, Getting the same error after upgrade with hermes enabled.

Comment: I also had this problem after upgrading to 0.66.
The only two solutions for me were to either disable hermes, or disable flipper (comment out use_flipper!())

Comment: @YaNuSH yeah I know, the point that I want to enable them both

Comment: @cuongtd let mw know if you ever find a solution. I ended up downgrading back to 0.65.1

Comment: I noticed they upgraded hermes from 0.8.1 to 0.9, so maybe if there is a way to downgrade only hermes it would solve the issue, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: @YaNuSH I don't know either, so confused about ios things. I see many people raised this issue in react-native repo but no one responded yet.

Comment: @YaNuSH I can run project now, check it from your end

Comment: Thanks @cuongtd! that actually worked

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I can run project successfully now by removing

```
DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING = NO;
```

in project.pbxproj

or go to **Build Settings** tab in Xcode then **enable** Dead Code Stripping for Debug mode

[image]

Comment: This solve it. But now my app crashed when started simulator

Comment: Worth noting that for some reason with flipper enabled on react-native this is *definitely* required for macCatalyst builds. It did not seem to be needed for flipper builds on ios for react-native 0.68.0.rc-2 at least (nor on 0.67) but for macCatalyst, definitely. https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/3117